# How to generate an array of Multiple recipients using mandrill

Tags: php, arrays, dynamic-arrays, mandrill

I need to send emails to multiple recipients. The number of recipients will vary depending on the data in the db.

Mandrill allows me to only add multiple recipients using an array.

Below is what works for multiple recipients

```
//email array that needs to be added to the 'to' key
$emailArray = ["example@example.com","test@test.com","hello@test.com","world@test.com"];

$mandrill = new Mandrill('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');   
$message = array(
          'subject' => 'Thanks for signing up',
          'from_email' => 'support@test.com',
          'to' => array(

           array(
                'email' => 'hello@test.com',
                'name' => 'Hello Test'
               ),

              array(
               'email' => 'goodbye@test.com',
                'name' => 'Goodbye Test',
              )


            ),

            'global_merge_vars' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'FIRSTNAME',
                    'content' => 'JOHN'
                    ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'LASTNAME',
                    'content' => 'DOE')

            ));

        //print_r($message);

        $template_name = 'hello-world';


        print_r($mandrill->messages->sendTemplate($template_name, $template_content, $message));
```

Below is what i need to generate dynamically depending on the length of the emailArray

```
to' => array(
           //the below array should be dynamically generated   
           array(
                'email' => 'hello@test.com',
                'name' => 'Hello Test'
               ),

              array(
               'email' => 'goodbye@test.com',
                'name' => 'Goodbye Test',
              )


            )
```

Here is the array. Currently with fixed values.

```
 //email array that needs to be added to the 'to' key
$emailArray = ["example@example.com","test@test.com","hello@test.com","world@test.com"];
```

My questions is How do generate the 'To' values based on the length of the email array?

is there a way i can implode the entire array script?

Comment: your 'array' is not valid php, and there is no question

Comment: Hi Dagon, this is the script that i have picked from the mandrill documents. I need to generate the 'To' values based on the length of the $emailArray.

Comment: $emailArray is not valid php, you you cant do anything with it as it stands

Comment: ok can you help me correct this ? 
should it be $array = array(
    "foo" => "bar",
    "bar" => "foo",
);

Comment: @Dagon The array syntax IS correct. Short array syntax [] instead of array() was added in PHP 5.4. http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php

Comment: Did you find an solution?

Comment: @william Yes William, the solution was simple. ran it in a for loop :/. But you need to initialise mandrill inside the for loop so that it works for every iteration.

Answer (score 1):

An effective way would be to use [array_map](https://www.php.net/array_map) I have added in some code that also takes an array of names as well (I couldn't see where you were getting the names from in your code).

```
$toAddresses = array('example@example.com','test@test.com','hello@test.com','world@test.com');
$names = array('Exmaple', 'Test', 'Hello', 'World');

$mandrillTo = array_map( function ($address, $name) {
    return array(
        'email' => $address,
        'name' => $name
    );
},
$toAddresses,
$names
);
```

This passes the 0th element from each array into the function and returns an array of two values, then passes the 1st, 2nd etc and returns each result in a new array ($mandrillTo)