# Mandrill sending multiple times

Tags: php, mandrill

I'm using mandrill for a newsletter,
It's only really simple stuff but I'm an idiot and I'm getting very confused, the code I'm using is adding on the email every loop through, rather than removing the one from before then adding the next one.

```
$mail->AddAddress($row->email);  // Add a recipient
```

this is the line that is incorrect, does anyone know a way to send each one individually because if, for example there are three people, the first person gets 3 copies:
(one to themself, one to themself and person 2, one to themself person 2 and person 3)
the second person gets 2
(one to themself and person 1, one to themself, person 1 and person 3) and I'm guessing you can guess what happens to person 3.

If this makes no sense please comment and I'll try to explain it a bit more.

Thanks,
P110

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass an array of emails to send in a batch, that will solve your problem.

You can check Mandrill documentation for an example: https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/messages.php.html

There is also explanation in this question: [How to generate an array of Multiple recipients using mandrill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20618901/how-to-generate-an-array-of-multiple-recipients-using-mandrill)